# Is there a way to use different mime type in my sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am creating my Api in Sinatra but i want for example use this routes:

`/places`
`/places.meta`
`/places.list`
`/users/id/places.list`

i have this working in rails but fails in sinatra

```
  def index
    case request.format.to_sym.to_s
    when 'list'
      result = Place.single_list(parameters)
    when 'meta'
      result = @parameters.to_meta
    else
      result = Place.get_all(parameters)
    end
    render json: result, status: 200
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinatra doesn't have a built-in concept of a "request format", so you have to manually specify a format-aware route pattern which Rails provide you automatically.

Here I use route pattern specified as a Regexp with a named capture:

```
require 'sinatra'

get /\/places(\.(?<format>meta|list))?/ do # named capture 'format'
  case params['format'] # params populated with named captures from the route pattern
  when 'list'
    result = Place.single_list(parameters)
  when 'meta'
    result = @parameters.to_meta
  else
    result = Place.get_all(parameters)
  end

  result.to_json # replace with your favourite way of building a Sinatra response
end
```